# How can we change the questions and options without changing text view and layout

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an quiz based application. I wanted to know like, how can we change the questions and its options without changing the text view where the question will appear and the layout when the user clicks next button i want the same text view and layout only question and its options should change.I am new to the android so can anyone help me out ..

Comment: please give code to explain very well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change the text of texview on click of next button like this

```
 TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
 Button next=(Button) findViewById(R.id.nextbutton);
 next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

     textView.setText("Your Text");

}
});
```